# C# Telerik RadGridview CellBeginEdit

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik

So this is my code

```
private void viewGroundMaintenance_CellBeginEdit(object sender, GridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
{
MessageBox.Show("Message");
}
```

when I'm clicking the cell the message box appears two times. Why is the message box showing two times. I want it to make it appear only one time per click.

Comment: events will be executed as many times as they are subscribed using += so please check with your subscription code and see how  many times it has been subscribed

Comment: I'm trying to debug it and found out that if I put the code e.Cancel = true; the events is running two times... :/

Answer (score 0):

I have just tested this with Q2 2015 SP1 and the event is triggered just once. Check if you have subscribed to the event more than once.